# a href moves because of hover transition

Tags: css

I am working on this site http://communicatieteam.nl/cvdw/

I have a problem with the lightboxes. The Boxes go to te next line if you hover over them because of the hover transition I am trying to make.

This is the HTML:

```
<section id="collegas">
     <h2>COLLEGA'S</h2>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_bas.jpg"><p>Bas</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_debbie.jpg"><p>Debbie</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_eefje.jpg"><p>Eefje</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_francien.jpg"><p>Francien</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_frank.jpg"><p>Frank</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_gonnie.jpg"><p>Gonnie</p></a>
 <a href="http://communicatieteam.nl/ons-team-2/"><img
    src="images/collega_henk.jpg"><p>Henk</p></a>
</section>
```

and this the css:

```
#collegas img {
    border: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    display:block;
}

#collegas img:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #e84e0e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #e84e0e;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #e84e0e;
  padding: 10px;
}

#collegas a {
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

How would you guys solve this? So the boxes stay in place? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height of `#collegas a` to a fixed value, such as 130px.

```
#collegas a {
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    height: 130px;
}
```